# Interview scheduling preferences in initial application?

Tags: interviewing, applications, scheduling

Is it considered 'bad form', or presumptuous to include scheduling preferences for interviews in your initial application letter?

For example "For interviews or other direct inquiries I am most easily available on Tuesdays and Fridays"

If it IS considered "not done", how can you most efficiently communicate this information without a lengthy email back-and-forth?

Comment: Why would there be 'lengthy email back-and-forth'? Usually either they ask you your preference first or they will ask 'Would Wednesday work for you?' You can just indicate your availability then.  I do not think this should be included in your initial application.

Answer (score 1):

I would most definitely consider it some degree of presumptuous, unless you had an valid reason for only being available at very specific times. What constitutes "valid" is of course depending on you, me, the line of work you're applying to and a multitude of other factors.

Generally if you make it more difficult for me or my organization to contact you inside normal business hours, it will count against you on some level, for simple practical reasons: there's a higher risk we find someone else before getting back to you if doing so is difficult.

This risk is mitigated somewhat if the organization gathers up all applicants from (say) the last three months and have "hiring days", and exacerbated if the company does ad-hoc hiring on the spot. Only you have a chance to know which is relevant to you.

On the other hand, if you genuinely have to way to, say, answer the phone outside of a very limited window, you don't lose anything by including that information, as not doing so would most likely just have led to a number of missed calls, which is just as bad or worse.

Source (such as it is): I occasionally read and filter applications (sometimes from large numbers of people), though I'm rarely the one to organize interviews from my final shortlist.

Comment: Doesn't providing full days on which contact is easiest during business hours make it easier rather than more difficult?

Comment: Yes, if those are genuinely the only possible times to contact you it is easier. However, it's always better to ensure you're reachable at all times unless it's impossible. Where this lies on a scale of "inconvenient" to "physically impossible" depends on your situation, of course. Which is why I say, if I didn't see it as a valid reason (or no reason was given), it might lead me to suspect your interest in the job was somewhat lacking, and hence it would count against you. You're never obligated to give a reason, but then we're back to the "presumptuous" part you asked about :)

Answer (score 1):

The statement:

> "For interviews or other direct inquiries I am most easily available
>   on Tuesdays and Fridays"

tells me nothing. It tells me that it is easier on you, but it tells me that the other days are still acceptable even if they are sub-optimal.

I know that if you have a job your ability to talk during business days may be limited. I know that if you are a student you have class times when you are unreachable.

But because I am likely to send you an email immediately if I can't reach you via phone, the fact Tuesdays and Fridays work best is not a concern.

Telling me these things too early doesn't help with scheduling. I only need to know it when it comes time to schedule the interviews.